# Recover txt files based on known strings

Tags: data-recovery

I have lost a number of txt files, which contain important personal information. I accidentally deleted them from the hard disk. I am not sure which folder they were in. I am not sure what filenames they had (at least not all of them), but I know some keywords that are likely to be in them. For example, I know most of them contain the string `diary` (you can guess why these files are important to me).

As far as I can understand, I can't use file carving tools like Scalpel, since they rely on identifying files based on their headers and footers, but txt files have neither.

So I guess my only option is to search for these known strings in the raw dump.

I have a dump of the FAT32 partition, a 150GB img file, created with `dd`.

As far as I understand FAT32 uses clusters of 4K. So any file smaller than 4K, which is the case for most of the txt files I am looking for, will be in one cluster. Some of them will span two or more clusters, perhaps contiguous, perhaps not.

So I think I need a tool, that can go through each cluster on the image, and grep for a list of keywords. If the cluster contains a match, it should be copied to a file, maybe just cluster001.txt, cluster002.txt, etc. Then I can manually piece these clusters together.

I would like to know if my reasoning and ideas make sense?

What tools can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible to consider mounting the image using the loopback system in Linux (something like: mount -o loop,ro image.img /mnt)? Then you could use the standard tools to search the filesystem.

Comment: Why can't you use normal file recovery software to determine if the data even still exists on the partition?

Comment: I don't know what 'normal' file recovery software is? TestDisk only lets me recover files if I know their location. Scalpel uses file carving, which I believe is not possible for txt files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any file recovery tool that selects files based on a specific string they contain, but these three methods should work:

1. When a file on a FAT32 partition is erased, its filename doesn't get overwritten. Only the first byte of the 8.3 filename gets set to *E5*, marking the file as deleted. This won't affect the extension, so TXT files are still easily recognizable.

   You can use any file recovery tool that lets you specify an extension (e.g., [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)), recover all TXT files and then search for *diary* in all recovered files.

   Since text files are (usually) small, recovering the text files shouldn't take much time (probably less than finding them). For a 150 GB partition, this should be rather quick.
2. Programs like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) identify files by their content and attempt to recover them. While it is true that text files don't have any headers, PhotoRec still manages to identify them (by exclusion, I suppose).

   Again, you could recover all text files and then search for *diary* in all recovered files.

   Identifying text files by their content will take longer than by their extension, but it will find files which directory entry has been overwritten as well.
3. Since you don't expect the text files to be big, you could also search for *diary* in the partition dump and recover the cluster containing it:

   ```
   sudo bash -c '
       for OFFSET in $(grep -abio diary /dev/sda3 | cut -d: -f 1); do
           ((CLUSTER = OFFSET / 4096))
           dd if=<imgfile> of=cluster$CLUSTER.txt bs=4096 skip=$CLUSTER count=1
       done
   '
   ```

   How it works:

   - `grep -Pabio diary /dev/sda3 | cut -d: -f 1` will print the byte offsets of every occurrence of the string *diary* in the image file.

     The `-i` switch makes the search case-insensitive. The `-P` switch turns on Perl-compatible Regular Expressions. This is needed because of a bug in some versions of (GNU) *grep* that makes case-insensitive searches unbearably slow unless you use PCRE.
   - `((CLUSTER = OFFSET / 4096))` calculates the offset in clusters from the offset in bytes.
   - `dd if=<imgfile> of=cluster$CLUSTER.txt bs=4096 skip=$CLUSTER count=1` writes the cluster at offset *X* in a file named *clusterX.txt*.

   By its nature, this will work only for files that fit in one cluster. You can increase *count* to recover more than one cluster and decrease *CLUSTER* to recover previous clusters as well.

   To recover three clusters (one before and one after the cluster containing *diary*), make the following changes:

   ```
   ((CLUSTER = OFFSET / 4096 - 1))

   dd ... count=3
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, complete and elaborate :) I won't have time to try this before tomorrow.

Comment: In fact I already tried your second suggestion: recovering all files  (or all txt files) with TestDisk, but I could not find a way to recover all files, except manually browsing through the system, and undeleting each one.

Comment: When PhotoRec asks for a partition, you can specify which file types you wan't to recover in *File Opt*. Press the right arrow key twice, then Enter.

Comment: To clarify: You have to use *PhotoRec*, not *TestDisk*.

Comment: This worked great! Btw you may need to add `z` to the `grep` options, if you get a message saying it has run out of memory. Also, for those who don't know you can put `/dev/sda3` in place of `<imgfile>`

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but might be useful to someone someday...

With WinHex you can run a “simultaneous search” of several keywords or expressions on the entirety of a partition, it will then display a list of hits, and if the file-system has been correctly analysed it will indicate which file each found string belongs to, even if the file has been deleted (it's not always reliable in FAT32 though, works better with a NTFS partition).